# Получение значения словаря по одному из элементов ключа

Tags: python, dict, index, tuple

Есть задача, заключающая в том, чтобы реализовать cli для изменения регистра строки

Пока имитировал ситуацию, написал так

```
CHOICE = {
    ('-l', '--lower'): 'lower',
    ('-u', '--upper'): 'upper',
    ('-t', '--title'): 'title',
    ('-c', '--capitalize'): 'capitalize'
}

str_ = 'HeLlO WoRlD'

print(getattr(str_, CHOICE['-l'])())
```

Опции `-l, --lower, ...` будут прилетать при запуске
`py test.py [OPTION] "HeLlO WoRlD"`

Но выводит ошибку
`KeyError: '-l'`

Что можно сделать, чтобы это работало?

P.S. Ещё есть такой вариант, где всё работает, но всё равно хотелось бы использовать первый вариант

```
CHOICE = {
    '-l': 'lower',
    '--lower': 'lower',

    '-u': 'upper',
    '--upper': 'upper',

    '-t': 'title',
    '--title': 'title',

    '-c': 'capitalize',
    '--capitalizer': 'capitalize',
}

str_ = 'HeLlO WoRlD'

print(getattr(str_, CHOICE['-l'])()) # hello world
```

Comment: По первому варианту словаря — только последовательным перебором ключей словаря. Лучше тогда описывать по первому варианту словаря, потом конвертировать во второй вариант, и по нему уже искать.

Answer (score 2):

Для разбора аргументов командной строки лучше использовать стандартный модуль [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). Тогда не будет проблем c короткими/длинными ключами параметров. И также можно будет определить ограничения на взаимоисключающие аргументы.
Пример:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My tool')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-l', '--lower',      dest="func", action='store_const', const='lower',      help='To lower string')
group.add_argument('-u', '--upper',      dest="func", action='store_const', const='upper',      help='To upper string')
group.add_argument('-t', '--title',      dest="func", action='store_const', const='title',      help='To title string')
group.add_argument('-c', '--capitalize', dest="func", action='store_const', const='capitalize', help='To capitalized string')
parser.add_argument('text', help='Text to convert')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(getattr(args.text, args.func)())
```

Вышеприведённый код сразу умеет вот это всё:

```
D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py
usage: test.py [-h] (-l | -u | -t | -c) text
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: text

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py "hEllO wOrlD"
usage: test.py [-h] (-l | -u | -t | -c) text
test.py: error: one of the arguments -l/--lower -u/--upper -t/--title -c/--capitalize is required

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -l "hEllO wOrlD"
hello world

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -u "hEllO wOrlD"
HELLO WORLD

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -t "hEllO wOrlD"
Hello World

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -c "hEllO wOrlD"
Hello world

D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -l -u "hEllO wOrlD"
usage: test.py [-h] (-l | -u | -t | -c) text
test.py: error: argument -u/--upper: not allowed with argument -l/--lower


D:\Programming\Python\1>test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] (-l | -u | -t | -c) text

My tool

positional arguments:
  text              Text to convert

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -l, --lower       To lower string
  -u, --upper       To upper string
  -t, --title       To title string
  -c, --capitalize  To capitalized string
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Но вопрос был конкретно про получение значения словаря по одному из элементов ключа)) А так я через click уже решил это)